# Почему на сайте на MODx главной страницей выскакивает вордпресс-настройки

Tags: modx, wordpress

Есть сайт http://labeng.ru/

Только что перекинул файлы с другого хостинга.

Но почему-то на главной настройки вордпресса вылазят. 
В чём может быть проблема?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Файлы от вордпресса в корне поверх лежат.
МОДх'овский путь http://labeng.ru/manager/ - посылает лесом.

В корне сайта должны быть папки assets и manager.

Если есть - попробуйте заменить файлы index.php и .htaccess на такие же из дистрибутива МОДх. (ht.access нужно переименовать  в .htaccess). 
Но старые не забудьте сохранить где-нибудь.

Comment: А в корне сайта итак есть папка assets и manager. И файлы также из дистрибутива.

Comment: Могу ли я предоставить доступ по FTP, чтобы кто-то посмотрел, в чём проблема?

Comment: 1. Значит это не корень сайта. 

Либо вы по ФТП ложите не в ту папку. 

Либо у вас не то прописанно в ДНС (или ещё не прописалось, если меняли) - и пользователи (или вы по ФТП) лазите не в тот сервер.

2. Думаю доступ не стоит. Вряд ли там лежит файл с номером вашей кредитной карты, чтоб я мог заказать себе чемодан контрацептивов и Машу за 500$/час, но зачем искушать других людей? ))

Comment: ОК. У меня на хостинге 2 домена. И получается так, что папка второго домена (на котором MODx), лежит в корне первого домена. Может что-то тут нетак?

Comment: Честно говоря странно. Обычно разные домены стараются разделять по разным папкам (по имени собственно домена в 95% случаев)... 

Папкой внутри обычно делаются сабдомены (домен вася.сом, а добавляем сабдомен.вася.сом), но, по ходу, это не ваш случай... Но в принципе, с папками проблем быть не должно .htaccess выше по дереву переписывает значение более низкого файла..

Проверьте, что оба .htaccess называются именно так. И вордпресса в корне и МОДха на папку выше... У вордпресса .htaccess не проблемный...

Ну... можно попробовать толкнуть хостера, чтоб разнес домены по папкам...